# Redrawing UI when keyboard closes

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with few EditText fields.When tapped on editext field, keyboard appears,
But while closing the keybaord, the UI elements that were behind the keybaord are redrawn.
The UI elements that were behind the keyboard just disappears for a moment while the keyboard is closing and reappears again.

I can use adjustPan,adjustResize in manifest file, but this will move entire screen up. ( I have master details view with details view in scrollview ).So, I am not using it.

Can someone please let me know if  there is any other approach to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit : i am using android 4.2.2

Answer (score 4):

try this in your Activity tag inside Manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```